# How can I send the Null Parameter on php soap request envelope?

Tags: php, soap, curl

I have been trying this for some days now without any success

This is my code:

```
<?$requestPesquisaTarifas = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<PesquisaTarifas xmlns="http://volator.com.br">
  <parTarifaHeader>
    <Sessao>
      <SiglaCiaAerea>string</SiglaCiaAerea>
      <IDSessao>long</IDSessao>
      <Verificador>string</Verificador>
      <MsgRetorno>string</MsgRetorno>
    </Sessao>
    <SegmentoIda>
      <Etapa>
        <Etapa xsi:nil="true" />
        <Etapa xsi:nil="true" />
      </Etapa>
      <IdFretamentoRotaTrechosVenda>int</IdFretamentoRotaTrechosVenda>
      <NroVoo>string</NroVoo>
      <SiglaOrigem>string</SiglaOrigem>
      <SiglaDestino>string</SiglaDestino>
      <TotalPaxADT>int</TotalPaxADT>
      <TotalPaxCHD>int</TotalPaxCHD>
      <TotalPaxINF>int</TotalPaxINF>
      <NroLugaresLivres>int</NroLugaresLivres>
      <Classe>Economica or Executiva or PrimeiraClasse</Classe>
      <IdaVolta>boolean</IdaVolta>
      <SiglaTarifaria>string</SiglaTarifaria>
    </SegmentoIda>
    <SegmentoVolta>
      <Etapa>
        <Etapa xsi:nil="true" />
        <Etapa xsi:nil="true" />
      </Etapa>
      <IdFretamentoRotaTrechosVenda>int</IdFretamentoRotaTrechosVenda>
      <NroVoo>string</NroVoo>
      <SiglaOrigem>string</SiglaOrigem>
      <SiglaDestino>string</SiglaDestino>
      <TotalPaxADT>int</TotalPaxADT>
      <TotalPaxCHD>int</TotalPaxCHD>
      <TotalPaxINF>int</TotalPaxINF>
      <NroLugaresLivres>int</NroLugaresLivres>
      <Classe>Economica or Executiva or PrimeiraClasse</Classe>
      <IdaVolta>boolean</IdaVolta>
      <SiglaTarifaria>string</SiglaTarifaria>
    </SegmentoVolta>
    <QtdPassageirosADT>int</QtdPassageirosADT>
    <QtdPassageirosCHD>int</QtdPassageirosCHD>
    <QtdPassageirosINF>int</QtdPassageirosINF>
    <SiglaClasseTarifariaIda>string</SiglaClasseTarifariaIda>
  </parTarifaHeader>
</PesquisaTarifas>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$cabecalhoPesquisaTarifas = array(
'POST /WSReservaweb.asmx HTTP/1.1',
'Host: webservice.oceanair.com.br',
'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
'Content-Length: '. strlen( $requestPesquisaTarifas ),
'SOAPAction: "http://volator.com.br/PesquisaTarifas"');

$curlPesquisaTarifas = curl_init(); // Iniciar o Curl

curl_setopt($curlPesquisaTarifas, CURLOPT_URL, $enderecoWsdlAvianca); // O Endereço que irá acessar 
curl_setopt($curlPesquisaTarifas, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Para Retornar o resultado
curl_setopt($curlPesquisaTarifas, CURLOPT_VERBOSE , false); // Modo Verbose, para exibir o processo na tela
curl_setopt($curlPesquisaTarifas, CURLOPT_HEADER , false ); // Se precisar de retorno dos cabeçalhos
curl_setopt($curlPesquisaTarifas, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); // Tempo máximo em segundos que deve esperar responder
curl_setopt($curlPesquisaTarifas, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $cabecalhoPesquisaTarifas); // Cabecalho para ser enviado 
curl_setopt($curlPesquisaTarifas, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Seguir redirecionamentos
curl_setopt($curlPesquisaTarifas, CURLOPT_POST, true); // Usar metodo post
curl_setopt($curlPesquisaTarifas, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestPesquisaTarifas); // Dados para serem processados
curl_setopt($curlPesquisaTarifas, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Caso precise verificar certificado

$resultadoPesquisaTarifa = curl_exec($curlPesquisaTarifas);

include ("arrayPesquisaTarifas.php");

include ("insertPesquisaTarifas.php");


?>
```

What am I missing? Every time I execute the code, I got this error:

```
soap:ClientServer was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (8, 36). ---> Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I checked and rechecked the row and columns specified, and can't see anything wrong in the xml. Any help would be highly appreciated; thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you just copied and pasted the definition for the SOAP header, without putting correct values. That way, the WebServer who is going to interpret those fields cannot understand what you are trying to get. You must verify exactly how the provider of the service interprets the data. For example, in:

```
<Classe>Economica or Executiva or PrimeiraClasse</Classe>
```

A correct input would be:

```
<Classe>Economica</Classe>
```

If you are struggling with web services try the following:

First, you must understand more about WebServices, SOAP and REST requests, WSDL and XML, a quick tour in www.w3schools.com is a good start.

Then, you need to check more information with the provider of the webservice about the meaning of each field and how the field values should be passed.

I also recommend SoapUI to test your SOAPs/REST requests when developing codes like that. It is a free program that you can download and is easy to manage.